# Пожилые женщины или женщины старшего возраста

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Которая из этих двух конструкций **"пожилые женщины"** или **"женщины старшего возраста"** звучит более формально и менее оскорбительно, если они имеют такую разницу.

Если же нет, то какова разница между этими двумя конструкциями?

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, конструкция **"женщины старшего возраста"** звучит более формально и менее оскорбительно, чем - **"пожилые женщины"**. Даже есть такое ощущение, что среди **"женщин старшего возраста"** могут быть и те, кто помоложе **"пожилых женщин"**.

Comment: Интересно, а с какого возраста начинается "старший возраст"

Comment: Объективного критерия нет, естественно. Если субъективно, то я бы сказал, что лет с пятидесяти.

Comment: По классификация АПН СССР, пожилые люди (другими словами,  старший возраст)  — от 61 до 75 (муж.); от 56 до 75 лет (жен.). А те, кто помоложе - среднего возраста

Comment: Та то по классификации АПН СССР, а по моей - с 50-ти.)

Answer (score 2):

Смотря в какой ситуации. Если обращаться к женщинам, лучше избегать таких слов вообще. Есть, конечно,выражения "женщины мудрого возраста","представительницы старшего поколения", "женщины бальзаковского возраста".

Можно же сказать просто "дорогие наши бабушки". Если официальная обстановка, можно сказать "представительницы третьего возраста"(1-юный, 2- зрелый, 3-пожилой).

Если произнесли "пожилые женщины", желательно оговорить:"пожилые в самом хорошем смысле - пожили, опыта набрались, пора передавать младшим поколениям". "Женщины старшего возраста"звучит помягче, но тоже обидно для тех, кто только ушёл на пенсию.

Лучше сказать "здесь собрались самые опытные и мудрые представительницы прекрасного пола".

Comment: К сожалению, речь идёт о причёсках, и я не представляю как эти два выражения можно было заменить на что-либо другое.

Comment: Как насчёт "женщин постарше", "умудрённых опытом"?

Comment: Молодец, Александр! В данной ситуации лучше сказать "женщины постарше", "женщины в возрасте".Поэтому я и говорю, что нужна ситуация

Comment: Для вашего сведения. Бальзаковский возраст -  "употребляется как шутливая характеристика женщин в возрасте 30 40 лет"

Comment: Ну, это сведения из словарей. Раньше так и считали, потому что ориентировались на его роман "Тридцатилетняя женщина", потом стали иметь в виду женщин от 30-40 и дальше лет без ограничения - возраст любви, когда  женщины уже начинали увядать, но ещё были прекрасны и  могли вызвать любовное чувство. В наше время этот возраст отодвинулся - некоторые и в 50 лет ещё очень даже ничего. Сам Бальзак влюблялся и в более старших.

Answer (score 2):

В титрах к сериалу «Обратная сторона Луны» обратил внимание на роли «Катя» и «Катя в возрасте». Такая немногословная характеристика (***женщина в возрасте***) не должна огорчить тех зрелых женщин и также их спутников, которые подошли к пятидесяти пяти и не готовы к часто звучащим: *пожилая женщина*, *пожилая пара*.

PS. О *женщинах*. На вывесках и в обращении характерно для больниц и бань. В салонах и парикмахерских по определению *женщина* становится *дамой*.

Answer (score 1):

Сколько лет этим женщинам? Если до 60, то можно сказать "женщины среднего возраста". Если еще старше, то "женщины среднего возраста и старше". Есть еще вариант "немолодые женщины", но это звучит немного грустно, как напоминание об ушедшей молодости.